# How to specify local folder in batch code

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following batch file code and I would like to modify it to not have to specify the path/folder, meaning just run it from the folder I want to list. How should I modify the ("g:\files*") part?

```
for %a in ("g:\files\*") do @echo %~na >> fileslist.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: Also, when I run it from the command prompt it works, but not from a batch file... :(

Comment: Don't put new questions into comments. Simply replace the folder inside the parentheses with a single `*`. In batch files you've double the for vars percent signs `%%a`

Comment: Thank you very much, that indeed solved it

Answer (score 0):

Running the above as a batch file, you need two `%` symbols. To use the batch files current location as the working directory, add `PushD %~dp0` to the start of your script:

`PushD %~dp0
for %%a in ("*") do @echo %%~na >> fileslist.txt`

[image]

Comment: I tried that but got - G:\files>getfiles
~na was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Are you actually running this FROM a batch file, or just in a command line?

Comment: Did you add double `%%` as per the example? Tested this myself and it works just fine for me. Screenshot attached.